# I am getting an error message while running a simple code in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.7

my code is `print("Hello Python World!")` written in Sublime 3.
While running the code, I get the following error:

This is the error message:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['python3', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\x\\Desktop\\python_work\\hello_world.py']]
[dir: C:\Users\x\Desktop\python_work]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Python37\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\]
[Finished]
```

Comment: Did you setup Sublime correctly? Looks like it's trying to run your file but it couldn't find it.

Comment: I can see python37 in the path at least, not sure if the windows version comes with some sort of alias.

Comment: @GeeTransit is right, you need to set up sublime correctly, you're using the linux config. vlizana, the path appears to be set up correctly, I'm also a windows and linuz user, boths OSes have benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried it in another pc following exactly the same steps and it worked fine. Not sure what the issue is with the sublime setup though. I will try re-installing from zero.